# Is GCP Firestore Native Mode export to BQ import supported?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I was exploring option to load Firestore Native Mode data (collection and documents) into BQ. But its not working out for me.

***Question***: Does Big Query support import of extract from Firestore Native export?

***Setup***: 1 collection with multiple documents (no sub collections).

***Steps***:
 - Export to Cloud Bucket: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import
 - Import in BQ: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore

***Error While loading in BQ***: 'Does not contain valid backup metadata'

***Analysis***: Its mentioned in the link that URI should have KIND_COLLECTION_ID and that file should end with [KIND_COLLECTION_ID].export_metadata. But none of these are true for Firestore Native mode export file. Its applicable for Firestore Datastore mode export.

- Verify [KIND_COLLECTION_ID] is specified in your Cloud Storage URI. If you specify the URI without 
  [KIND_COLLECTION_ID], you receive the following error: does not contain valid backup metadata. (error 
  code: invalid)
- The URI for your Cloud Firestore export file should end with [KIND_COLLECTION_ID].export_metadata. 
  For example: default_namespace_kind_Book.export_metadata. In this example, Book is the collection ID, 
  and default_namespace_kind_Book is the file name generated by Cloud Firestore

Comment: I tried to recreate your issue but it worked just fine for me.  Can you 100% check which file you used from your GCS bucket?  For my test, the full path was [Bucket]/[Date-time]/all_namespaces/kind_[collection]/all_namespaces_kind_[collection].export_metadata ...

Comment: Thanks for responding!
Are you sure that you are using Native mode or is it Datastore mode. On export to Bucket from firestore, GCP creates a folder like this everytime: 2019-10-24T12:13:17_27544/
 Folder has following for me:
 File - 2019-10-30T13:12:58_36484.overall_export_metadata
 Folder - export0/ contatins 2 files:  export0.export_metadata and output-0
 Folder - export1/ contatins 2 files:  export1.export_metadata and output-0

Comment: I am pretty sure I was using Firestore native mode.  Can you update the question with the exact command you used to export the data?

Comment: Same as mentioned in link above, gcloud beta firestore export gs://firestore_export

Comment: What is the exact path and full name of the GCS object you used for import into BQ?

Comment: This is the challenge on how to give path because as the link suggest, "The URI for your Cloud Firestore export file should end with [KIND_COLLECTION_ID].export_metadata" . In only get files in export as mentioned in my 31st Oct post. So there is no file with suggested name. Not sure what I am doing wrong here!

Answer (score 1):

When one creates an export of firestore collections to GCS, a directory structure is created that looks like:

```
[Bucket]
  - [Date/Time]
    - [Date/Time].overall_export_metadata
    - all_namespaces
      - kind_[collection]
        - all_namespaces_kind_[collection].export_metadata
```

When one imports an export into BigQuery, use the file:

```
[Bucket]/[Date/Time]/all_namespaces/kind_[collection]/all_namespaces_kind_[collection].export_metadata
```

Specifically, if one uses `[Bucket]/[Date/Time]/[Date/Time].overall_export_metadata` you will get the error you described.  See also the note [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#loading_cloud_firestore_export_service_data) under Console > Bullet 3 which reads:

> Note: Do not use the file ending in overall_export_metadata. This file
>   is not usable by BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a pipeline from Firestore to Bigquery you should manualy format the Firestore collection to a Bigquery Table. I have used [gcloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart), [cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) and [firestore batched operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#python_2) to migrate the data from Firestore to Bigquery. I created an example code [here](https://github.com/juanda2222/playground/blob/master/firestore/firestore_to_bigquery.py)